# How to fetch records from mysql and check for updates without setinterval or load functions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website which I am working on, just like social web but it is in a simple codes of php, jquery and html.I have made my site updates with jquery load function with interval. User is updated by this load function with interval of 3 seconds. I needed something else which fetch records from mysql and update them again and again because wall posts , likes and unlikes , delete and time ago runs fine but when it comes to comment it is weird because after 3 seconds, the comment which is typed in textarea by the user gets vanished due to this load function. I liked this function but I think it is not accurate for this type of job. So, I need a simple solution of this.

Comment: You need a real-time web application. You could try node.js for that, for instance. Not sure if a 15 yo-kid can understand, though.

Comment: man if 15 year old kid can get all that working then some day he will also make a real-time web app :P

Answer (score 0):

Recently I discover this plugin: https://github.com/paulirish/jquery-idletimer to detect when the users goes idle, perhaps you can update your information based on this.

Comment: Thats good man awesome but i have to see whether it works nice with my website.......when user get idle then no updates and when he is moving mouse then get updates......because when writing comment he will be in idle state..thanks buddy but i need more...

Comment: hey man i want it to get updates when idle or active but i don't want it to get updates when focusing on textarea. can you make a code for me. just make that body background changes for both idle and active but when focusing on textarea if the user is idle then not change background.